# What are the numbers next to the items when forging in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

When forging armor and weapons at the blacksmith what are the numbers next to each item?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is, based on the money and mats on your person, how many of that item you can make.

As you make one of those items, you'll see the numbers changing because you do not have enough materials to make the same number again.

It was a really useful tool in WoW when trying to level. You could see which ones would give you the best bang for your buck. It's less useful in D3.

Comment: Ahh...it includes $$$ too. I was confused because I had more than enough materials to craft but the number was lower than I was expecting. Hence the question.

Answer (score 2):

The number shows how many of that item you have materials to craft. For example, you can craft 3 Apprentice Leather Belts.

Answer (score 1):

That's how many of that item you currently have the materials to craft.